# Соединение таблиц sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем доброго времени суток!

Я новичок в SQL, выполняя задание наткнулась на такую схему:

```sql
select count(*) 
from testdat, 
     testart 
where testdat.testart = testart.code 
  and testart.meaning = 'function' 
  and testdat.valid is null;
```

Может мне пожалуйста кто-нибудь помочь объяснить этот кусочек кода Впервые сталкиваюсь с таким соединением через . и =

Всех заранее благодарю

Comment: Покажите минимальную структуру таблиц testdat, testsrt  и как они связаны. Выражение ``from testdat, testart`` означает декартово произведение (каждый с каждым) двух таблиц. Выражение ``(testdat.testart = testart.code and testart.meaning = 'function' and testdat.valid is null)`` можно рассматривать как одно условие

Comment: `.` - это разделитель между именем таблицы и полем таблицы, `=` это в данном случае проверка равенства на значение после `=` , `and` - это логический операнд обозначающий одновременное исполнение в данном случае условий. `count(*)` посчитает количество строк в обоих таблицах которые будут удовлетворять нижеописанным условиям, в результате выведется одно число.

Answer (score 1):

Соединение через запятую `select … from a,b` — это элемент синтаксиса первого стандарта SQL 1987 года. Соответствует `CROSS JOIN` в более поздних версиях.

При добавлении WHERE условия сравнения столбцов из обеих таблиц, CROSS JOIN становится эквивалентным INNER JOIN, например `select … from a,b where a.field=b.field` == `select … from a cross join b where a.field=b.field` == `select … from a inner join b on a.field=b.field`

Таким образом приведённый запрос эквивалентен

```
select count(*) 
from testdat 
join testart on testdat.testart = testart.code 
where testart.meaning = 'function' 
  and testdat.valid is null;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь